# Is there a way to avoid @charset error in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3

I tried to import styles into my vuejs file by doing this

```
<style scoped>
@import '../assets/front/css/bootstrap.min.css';
@import '../assets/front/css/all.min.css';
@import '../assets/front/css/slick.css';
@import '../assets/front/css/simple-line-icons.css';
@import '../assets/front/css/style.css';
</style>
```

But anytime i run `npm run dev` i get this error
`WARN  [vite:css] @charset must precede all other statements` 
The project is in Nuxt3 by the way.

Here is the link to [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-udmxks)

Comment: Try to comment out each line one by one to find out who is the culprit.

Comment: @kissu so i have done that the so the error is shows when i include this file ```@import '../assets/front/css/slick.css';``` how can i avoid this??

Comment: What do you have in that file?

Comment: so i have ```@charset "UTF-8"``` in between the css file line, i have removed this and i do not have the error anymore.

Comment: Why would you have that in the first place?

Comment: i did not put it, it came with the theme i downloaded.

Comment: You could probably remove it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

No need to completely remove `@charset "UTF-8"`, just move it so it's on the first line of the file. The file that needs this change will probably be linked in the warning message.